# Simplifying Radical Expression $\frac23\sqrt{\frac92}+\frac32\sqrt[3]{16}+\frac14\sqrt{72}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Simplify$$\frac23\sqrt{\frac92}+\frac32\sqrt[3]{16}+\frac14\sqrt{72}$$

My try: 
$$\frac23\cdot\frac3{\sqrt2}+3\sqrt[3]{2}+\frac32\sqrt{2}$$
$$\sqrt2+3\sqrt[3]{2}+\frac32\sqrt{2}$$
$$3\sqrt[3]{2}+\frac52\sqrt{2}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't too sure if I could combine the cube root and the square root somehow

Comment: @suomynonA You can't "combine" them further, unless maybe you consider $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}(6 + 5 \sqrt[6]{2})$ to be "simpler", which most people wouldn't.